# read xml document and update all fields c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i'm trying to read xml file and update all it's value my xml was

```
<adf>
    <prospect>
        <requestdate>2015-10-29 07-38-22</requestdate>
        <id sequence="1" source="admin.ss.com">admin.ss.com</id>
        <vehicle interest="buy" status="">
            <id sequence="1" source=""></id>
            <year></year>
            <make></make>
            <model>camry</model>
            <vin></vin>
            <stock></stock>
            <trim></trim>
        </vehicle>
        <customer>
            <contact primarycontact="1">
                <name part="first">Jessica</name>
                <name part="last">Sonntag</name>
                <email>js@test.com</email>
                <phone type="phone" time="day">555-585-5555</phone>
                <address>
                    <street line="1"></street>
                    <city></city>
                    <regioncode></regioncode>
                    <postalcode></postalcode>
                    <country></country>
                </address>
            </contact>
            <comments>Vehicle Year: 2011 Comments: </comments>
        </customer>
        <provider>
            <name part="full">ST</name>
            <service> Engine Marketing</service>
            <phone>1-866-572-3952</phone>
        </provider>
    </prospect>
</adf>
```

so i select node like below

```
 var items = (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("requestdate")
                         select item).ToList();
```

then i can update only requestdata tag value so do i have to repeat same for all tags or is there any good way to accomplish this.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have came up with solution with support two extension method i'm iterating all nodes and update.(since my xml is not too big or complicated this one would be a good solution) 
with help of these two extension methods

```
public static void IterateThroughAllNodes(this XmlDocument doc, Action<XmlNode> elementVisitor)
{
    if (doc != null && elementVisitor != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
        {
            DoIterateNode(node, elementVisitor);
        }
    }
}

public static void IterateThrough(this XmlNodeList nodes, Action<XmlNode> elementVisitor)
{
    if (nodes != null && elementVisitor != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            DoIterateNode(node, elementVisitor);
        }
    }
}

private static void DoIterateNode(XmlNode node, Action<XmlNode> elementVisitor)
{
    elementVisitor(node);
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        DoIterateNode(childNode, elementVisitor);
    }
}
```

then i can update my xml nodes as below

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xmlmail.xml"));
var email = new XmlEmail();
doc.IterateThroughAllNodes(
    delegate(XmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.Name.Equals("requestdate"))
            node.InnerText= email.RequestDate.ToLongDateString();
        if (node.Name.Equals("vehicle"))
        {
            XmlNodeList childs = node.ChildNodes;
            childs.IterateThrough(delegate(XmlNode vnode)
            {
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("id"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.VehicleId.ToString();
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("year"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Year.ToString();
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("make"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Make;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("model"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Model;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("vin"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Vin;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("trim"))
                    vnode.InnerText = email.Trim;
            });
        }
        if (node.Name.Equals("customer"))
        {
            XmlNodeList childs = node.ChildNodes;
            childs.IterateThrough(delegate(XmlNode vnode)
            {
                if (vnode.Attributes != null && (vnode.Name.Equals("name") && vnode.Attributes["part"].Value.Equals("first")))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.FirstName;
                if (vnode.Attributes != null && (vnode.Name.Equals("name") && vnode.Attributes["part"].Value.Equals("last")))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.LastName;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("email"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Email;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("phone"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Phone;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("comments"))
                    vnode.InnerText= email.Comments;
                if (vnode.Name.Equals("address"))
                {
                    XmlNodeList addresschilds = vnode.ChildNodes;
                    addresschilds.IterateThrough(delegate(XmlNode anode)
                    {
                        if (anode.Name.Equals("street"))
                            anode.InnerText= email.Street;
                        if (anode.Name.Equals("city"))
                            anode.InnerText= email.City;
                        if (anode.Name.Equals("phone"))
                            anode.InnerText= email.Phone;
                        if (anode.Name.Equals("regioncode"))
                            anode.InnerText= email.RegionCode;
                        if (anode.Name.Equals("postalcode"))
                            anode.InnerText= email.Postalode;
                        if (anode.Name.Equals("country"))
                            anode.InnerText= email.Country;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do this. This one is a hidden gem. Most people may not know this. This feature came in VS2013 and it's called "Paste XML as Classes."

1. Save your xml (Ex: MyXml.XML)
2. Create a new Console project
3. Open the Xml in Visual studio
4. Copy All contents of the xml (Ctl+A,  Ctl + C)
5. Add a new class to your project. You can give any name you like.
6. Go to Edit>Paste Special>Paste XML as classes.
7. Add another class to your project. Then add below two methods to that class.

   ```
     public static string Serialise<T>(T serialisableObject)
     {
       var doc = new XmlDocument();
       using (var stream = new StringWriter())
       {
           var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
           settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

           XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
           var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
           ns.Add("", "");

           var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
           xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, serialisableObject, ns);
           doc.LoadXml(stream.ToString());
       }
       return doc.InnerXml;
   }

   public static T Deserialise<T>(string xml)
   {
       T list;
       using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
       {
           var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
           list = (T)serialiser.Deserialize(reader);
       }
       return list;
   }
   ```

Then in your console applications Main method; add this.

```
            var myObj = new adf();
            myObj.prospect =  new adfProspect();
            myObj.prospect.customer =  new adfProspectCustomer(){comments = "dgsrtetetete"};
            //populate all fields.....

            var xml = MySerializer.Serialise(myObj);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myNewXml.xml", xml);
```

That's it. Same way now you can deserialise an xml object in to your class.

Comment: Kosala W. i tried this way as well but looking for LinqToXml way to solve it out

Comment: Lnq to xml way is ok if your xml is not very complicated. `xmlDoc.Descendants()` will give you all elements in your xml. But then if you have the same child element name under different parents, you will find it hard to understand which data should go to which element. To find the correct parent, you may write `var vehicle = xDoc.Elements("adf").Elements("prospect").Elements("vehicle");`, and then fill in sub elements. Finally save the document. But any of the Linq to Xml methods will eliminate the risk of assigning values to the wrong element due to confusions with other elements.

Comment: thanks kosala w. i have came up with a solution i'll post here for reference

Comment: I will post some code for LinqToXml as soon as i can. (Just noticed you found a solution. So all good I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the XmlSerializer class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx If you serialize/deserialize the xml then up dating is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to change every phone number to "0123456789" you could do something like:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("document.xml");

var results = from phone in xDoc.Descendants("phone") select phone;

foreach (XElement result in results)
{
    element.SetValue("0123456789");
}
```